# Error 522: Connection timed out

Tags: cloud, cloudflare

We couldn't able to access to application(www.xxxxx.net) from office location.But i can able to access the outside network and attached screen shot for same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review CloudFlare's documentation on [CloudFlare 522 errors](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out).

General cause: something blocking requests from our IPs at your host/on your server.